# Best practice in dealing with xpages extensions dialog box?

Tags: xpages

I have an extension pages dialog box that I placed in a custom control.   The dialog box is used to search for cost centers and return information such as market, cost center number, cost center name etc.

A "Select" button is pressed and the dialog box appears.   The user searches for  and selects their cost center.  The OK button is pressed and it closes the dialog box and updates the various fields on the xPage.

A couple of questions.

1. Currently the "Select" button on the CC needs to know and refer to the name of the dialog box control within the CC.  Seems to me that this is not the best practice.   My end user programmer needs to know the ID of that dialog box control within the CC.   Is there any way for my "Select" button could "show" the CC and the CC would actually show the dialog box control?
2. My CC makes use of custom properties to store the various document fields from the selected cost center.   The OK button then uses these properties to set the various fields on the xPage.  This again does not seem to be a best practice.  If I wanted to use that CC  in another application then I might need to edit the code in the OK button.   Is there a better way to deal with this?   Like I can set properties for a CC when I drop it on my xPage, is there a way I can tell it the code that I want to execute when the OK button is pressed?

One thing I thought was to have properties for the fields that need to be updated by the OK button but that does not seem to be so flexible.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue of needing to know the id not sure if theres a typo but I don't understand why its bad that a select button inside a cc needs to no the id of the dialog to open it? did you mean the select is outside the cc? either way have you tried anything like creating a property on the custom control so that from outside it you can set something maybe

```
<xc:mycustomControl showDialog="false">
```

and then when something outside it happens change showDialog and refresh the cc, then inside the cc you can have a before / after page load to determine what happens when showDialog is true / false.

For your second issue it sounds to me like this should be using a domino document structure. Rather than the dialog pulling out each piece and the ok button updating, what I would do is have a domino doc data source on the page. when something is selected through the dialog I would update the document this source is pointing to and have all the fields bound to what ever fields they need to be. This way after something is selected the fields will just update to what ever the document contains, and it will be much more re useable so long as the domino docs have the same field names

Comment: Yes the Select button is outside the CC on the xPage.  My dialog box is inside the CC.  My end user programmer drops the CC inside the Xpage.   My end user programmer shouldn't need to worry about the internal workings of the CC just what is exposed to him.  It has been that way with every object oriented program I have ever worked with.

Comment: For the second issue I was just thinking about using a domino doc as a property for the CC instead of individual properties.   So the CC searches for a cost center and sets the domino do property.   But I still need to preform some action with the returned.  I should be able to allow my end user programmer to "plug in" that action when he places the CC.  Just like he might set a property.

Comment: I'm not sure of the entire use case, i might be missing something but if everything else is inside the custom control it sounds like it would be easier to have the select in there as well just because it would avoid that issue. As for the domino doc, I'm not sure what else the user would want to do with the details other than edit / save, both of which can be easily handled by bounding the fields to the document fields and providing a simple save action.

Comment: Theres also the <xp:callback facetName="testfacet"> that would allow an end user to add there own controls to a custom control by using <xp:this.facets><xp:panel xp:key="testFacet"></></>. then maybe you can provide a way for them to add there own functionality by adding buttons / actions to this facet? no sure if that willfit in with the use case or not

Comment: Simon.  It is a Dialog Box.   The Select button displays the dialog box.  If the select button was placed on the control, even through a facet then the button would need to be confined to the area that the CC occupies. Most times that is not were you will want the button to appear.

Comment: ok maybe i'm not seeing the use case but from a useablity stand point having a button next to the controls it will be affecting is logically correct. If your enabling save and edit with these details for a user then it would make sense to have an actions bar with all 3 buttons or select on the top. Also with some good css you could provide a property that would determine where to place it e.g. top, bottom, left, right etc. so as not to limit the end developer if this is an issue. sounds easier to deal with than generating partial refreshs for the sake of placing it outside.

Comment: did this work out in the end? if so can you mark as top answer, if not add more details and I or others will help